# Display only specific labels, using eigenvector centrality (igraph in R)

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking, sna

I am using [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) version 0.99.879 and [igraph](/questions/tagged/igraph) version 1.0.1.

My question is rather similar to [Show only specific labels on network graph using igraph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262906/show-only-specific-labels-on-network-graph-using-igraph-in-r/32265132#comment80639723_32265132). I have posted my follow-up question on this as a comment there, but was asked to open a new question.

I also want to display only specific vertex labels and this works fine if you use the [degree](/questions/tagged/degree) or [betweenness](/questions/tagged/betweenness) centrality function. However, I tried it with [eigenvector](/questions/tagged/eigenvector) or [hub](/questions/tagged/hub) centrality and it shows the following error

> Error in ifelse(evcent(g) > 0.1, V(g)$name, NA) :    (list) object
>   cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Here is the code:

```
#random graph
library(igraph)

g <- graph( c("John", "Jim", "Jim", "Jack", "Jim", "Jack", "Brian", "John", "John", "Janis", "Janis", "Jennifer", "Justin", "John"), 
                   isolates=c("Jesse", "Brian") )
# works perfectly fine
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(0,0,1,0))
plot(g, vertex.size=9,
     vertex.label = ifelse(betweenness(g) > 0, V(g)$name, NA),
     edge.arrow.size=.5)
plot(g, vertex.size=9,
     vertex.label = ifelse(degree(g) > 0, V(g)$name, NA),
     edge.arrow.size=.5)
#does not work
plot(g, vertex.size=9,
     vertex.label = ifelse(evcent(g) > 0.01, V(g)$name, NA),
     edge.arrow.size=.5)
# I also tried this with no success
eig <- evcent(g)
par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(0,0,1,0))
plot(g, vertex.size=9,
     vertex.label = ifelse(eig$vector > 0.1, V(g)$name, NA),
     edge.arrow.size=.5)
```

How can this be fixed. What exactly does this mean:

> 'type double'

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the help page `?evcent`.  It says:

> Value
>
> A named list with components:  ...

You need to use

```
ifelse(evcent(g)$vector > 0.01,
```

and similarly,  use `hub_cent$vector`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I am wondering whether is not rather `ifelse(evcent(g)$vector > 0.4, V(g)$name, NA)` since I am interested in the eigenvector score of the nodes?

Comment: You are right.  It should be vector - not value.  I will change the answer so as not to be confusing to others.